# send_mail() in django is not sending. Command line sendmail is

Tags: django, sendmail

I have a linux laptop. I am trying to test out some email functionality in my django app and I can't seem to get send_mail or EmailMessage to work.

Here is my sendmail:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        send_mail(
            'Subject here',
            'Here is the message.',
            'me@pop-os.domain',
            ['me@gmail.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        return HttpResponse('Message sent')
```

When I go to the page it prints a successful email message in the Terminal:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Subject here
From: me@po-pos.domain
To: me@gmail.com
Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2020 19:13:36 -0000
Message-ID: <160373961632.78488.2486155271127153156@pop-os.localdomain>

Here is the message.
```

I never receive the message in my gmail. I've changed to From and To to mask the actual email addresses. What could I be doing wrong? If I use the command line to sendmail like this it works.

sendmail user@example.com  < /tmp/email.txt

Comment: You tagged this as `sendmail`. Are you really  using the UNIX program `sendmail`?

Comment: I was getting nothing so I installed sendmail. Then I stated getting smtp errors in django, so I’m assuming it needed sendmail

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to add some lines in your `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.pop-os.domain'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your-mail@pop-os.domain'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

Comment: I do have those settings. How do I verify my smtp port?

Comment: when you send mail from `me@pop-os.domain` you need in settings also have login and password for those domain. and look for smtp port in documentation